# How do you change the runtime version for JavaFX on Mac?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm pretty new in programming so please don't hate if some words are used incorrectly...
I have to install JavaFX for my programming class. But my runtime version is too high (54 instead of 52).
So I went to Properties > Java Building Path and edited the JRE System Library like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3YAJ.png) because that's what I (thought I) find out from similar questions. But it did not work out, the same error occurred. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it to do with compatibility between the compiler version and the runtime version? Or between the Java (runtime) version and the JavaFX version?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: If it's for your own, personal use, you can download Oracle's JDK 1.8 for free and use it for your studies. It includes JavaFX. Download link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: "...don't hate if some words are used incorrectly...", we don't hate.  We correct. No bad intention from either you or us. :D